# how to modify chart web part by using the data of document library columns in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, chart-web-part

I know that it's possible to connect data from list to chart web part , but is there some way to create 
chart web part on document library columns  ?

without of course  export it to excel ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A library is just a type of list. If the library column has numeric data, it can be charted with the chart web part.